# In 5e If a Ranger takes "Constructs" as a favored enemy, does that include Warforged?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, constructs

Simple questions for "Rules as Written" that came up in our newest Eberron campaign.

If a Ranger takes "Constructs" as a favored enemy, does that include Warforged?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, since both questions are asking “do warforged count as constructs?”

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Warforged aren't constructs

They simply don't have a trait which makes them constructs, so they are humanoids (like most other races by default). Unlike, say, Satyrs which have an explicit trait that makes them Fey. *Monsters of the Multiverse* actually clarifies this best:

> Every creature in D&D, including each player character, has a special tag in the rules that identifies the type of creature they are. Most player characters are of the Humanoid type.

Your ranger can choose to have Warforged as one of their two humanoid races though, if choosing that mode of Favored Enemy:

> Alternatively, you can select two races of humanoid (such as gnolls and orcs) as favored enemies.